# JPA Query gets error InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I've written a query

```
public interface TeabagRepository extends CrudRepository<Teabag, Long> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT t.post, t.status, t.expires FROM teabags t WHERE t.status = 'hot' AND t.user_id = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
    Teabag findTea(Long id);
}
```

I set `spring.jpa.show-sql=true` in `application.properties`

So the query is shown in the console, I ran this query in database and it works:

```
SELECT
    t.post,
    t.status,
    t.expires 
FROM
    teabags t 
WHERE
    t.status = 'hot' 
    AND t.user_id = ?
```

**The error:**

> 2018-05-08 19:22:27.675 ERROR 1259 --- [nio-8080-exec-4]
>   o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for
>   servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
>   [Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could
>   not execute query; SQL [SELECT t.post, t.status, t.expires
>   FROM teabags t WHERE t.status = 'hot' AND t.user_id = ?]; nested
>   exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not
>   execute query] ****with root cause
>
> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column name id was not found in
>   this ResultSet.****
>
> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could
>   not execute query; SQL [SELECT t.post, t.status, t.expires FROM
>   teabags t WHERE t.status = 'hot' AND t.user_id = ?];

**update:** more error text

> nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query

**root error**

> with root cause
>
> > org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column name id was not found in
> >     this ResultSet.

Why isn't this query working in the spring boot application?

Comment: What's the root cause saying? There is another, causing exception that contains the actual reason.

Comment: I'm not sure where the root is coud be this: Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column name id was not found in this ResultSet.

Comment: but if the query couldn't be executed don't think resultset would be related to error since there is not result

Comment: Without the full stack trace and information necessary to analyze what's going coming in drop by drop it's quite hard for me to diagnose properly the cause.

Comment: thats all the error..

Comment: What is the column name in your entity for property `Tea.user_id`? also is your property name in Entity class is `user_id`?

Comment: Also, your repository is for entity `Tea` whereas query is for entity `teabags`

Comment: yes that has nothing to do with the error though

Answer (score 1):

The result was expecting every column of the Teabag so I had to select t.*

```
@Query(value = "SELECT t.* FROM teabags t WHERE t.status = 'hot' AND t.user_id = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
    Teabag findTea(Long id);
```